# AngularJS $routeParams: Set $scope variables

Tags: angularjs, angular-router

Using AngularJS 1.6.1, I have a page with just one controller. I would like to set $scope variables to the values of (optional) route parameters using $routeParams. But unfortunately this doesn't work at all:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
         templateUrl: '/partials/partial1.htm'
      })
      .when('/:artist/:album', {
         templateUrl: '/partials/partial1.htm'
      })
      .otherwise({
         redirectTo: '/'
      });
});

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
   $scope.artist = $routeParams.artist;
   $scope.album = $routeParams.album;
});
```

When using console.log I can see that the values are being set ... but it seems like the router is initiating a separate controller for the parameterized route. So I tried it with an additional controller and then using $emit and $on to pass a message from the second to the first controller.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
         templateUrl: '/partials/partial1.htm'
      })
      .when('/:artist/:album', {
         templateUrl: '/partials/partial1.htm',
         controller: 'URLController'
      })
      .otherwise({
         redirectTo: '/'
      });
});

myApp.controller('URLController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
   $scope.$emit('UrlChanged', $routeParams.artist, $routeParams.album);
});

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
   $scope.$on('UrlChanged', function(event, artist, album) {
      $scope.artist = $routeParams.artist;
      $scope.album = $routeParams.album;
      // CORRECTION: It keeps firing events if I add this
      $scope.loadAlbum();
      // loadAlbum() contains a call to a Rest API on the same server via $http.get.
      // Obviously this triggers the creation of a new URLController????
   });
});
```

but this just keeps firing `UrlChanged` events indefinitely.

CORRECTION: It *only* keeps firing if I add an `$http.get` call

What will I have to do to achieve my goal?

Comment: Probably instead of emitting your own event in the new controller, you can try to listen to the [`$routeChangeSuccess`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.10/docs/api/ngRoute/service/$route#event-$routeChangeSuccess) event of the `$route` service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try listening to [`$routeChangeSuccess`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.10/docs/api/ngRoute/service/$route#event-$routeChangeSuccess) event of the `$route` service (since `MainController` seems to be initialized before the actual event/navigation occurs):

```
myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function ($event, next, current) {
        var params = next.params;
        if (params) {
            $scope.artist = params.artist;
            $scope.album = params.album;
        }
    });
}])
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I already tried $locationChangeSuccess ... but that was the wrong place